# MySQL Left Join 4 tables with null duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm stuck with a query, I'll start backwards with the results in case this is obvious then provide more detail.

The user follows a sponsor who follows a supplier, I'm trying to show all products with the userid for a sponsored suppliers product where the userid exists, NULL for no userid.

```
Desired result (userid = 1):
productid |  supplierid  |  userid
    1            1            1
    2            1            1
    3            2           Null
    4            3            1
    5            2           Null
    6            3            1

Actual result (userid = 1):
productid |  supplierid  |  userid
    1            1            1
    1            1           Null
    2            1            1
    2            1           Null
    3            2           Null
    4            3            1
    4            3           Null
    5            2           Null
    6            3            1
    6            3           Null
```

My Query:

```
SELECT product.productid, product.supplierid, usersponsor.userid FROM product 
INNER JOIN supplier ON product.supplierid = supplier.supplierid
LEFT JOIN sponsorsupplier ON sponsorsupplier.supplierid = product.supplierid
LEFT JOIN usersponsor ON usersponsor.sponsorid = sponsorsupplier.sponsorid and usersponsor.userid = 1
```

I have 4 tables

```
sponser
supplier
product
myuser
```

With these 2 linking tables:

```
usersponsor
sponsorsupplier
```

Example tables:

```
myuser:userid
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5

Sponsor:sponsorid
  1
  2
  3

Supplier:supplierid
  1
  2
  3

usersponsor
userid     |   sponsorid
  1        |       1     <- user 1 follows sponsor 1
  2        |       2
  2        |       3

sponsorsupplier
sponsorid  |   supplierid
  1        |       1     <- supplys product 1,2 (sponsor 1)
  1        |       3     <- supplys product 4,6 (sponsor 1)
  2        |       2 
  2        |       1
  3        |       3     


Product
productid  |  supplierid
  1        |      1       <-
  2        |      1       <-
  3        |      2
  4        |      3       <-
  5        |      2
  6        |      3       <-
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate a subquery:

```
SELECT
    p.productid
  , p.supplierid
  , ss.userid
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            ss.supplierid
          , MIN( us.userid ) userid
        FROM sponsorsupplier ss
        INNER JOIN usersponsor us ON ss.sponsorid = us.sponsorid
        WHERE us.userid = 1
        GROUP BY
            ss.supplierid
    ) ss ON p.supplierid = ss.supplierid
ORDER BY
    p.productid;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a very elegant solution. I didn't realise that you can put everything into a subquery then outer join into it.

Comment: Not just in reducing rows to join. There are occasions when using an aggregation in one or more subqueries is the only way to get the right numbers. Aggregating over multiple joins can adversely skew results due to the multiplier effect of joins.